# Catching " 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' Exception happening during asynchronous web service call

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, exception

I am creating an application that consumes a SOAP web service in C#. I generated a proxy class for the web service WSDL using the `svcutil` tool.

I added the proxy class to my code and I am using it to make calls to the web service and get results asynchrounsly.

Everything works pretty fine when the client has an Internet access. However, if I run attempt to access while the application doesn't have Internet access it crashes raising the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException' occurred in
System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll but was not handled in user code
```

I am trying to catch this exception to prevent the application from crashing and provide the user with a more friendly error message, However, since I am doing async web calls,  simply surrounding the web service calls by a `try`- `catch` does not help.

According to the exception details it happens in the `End_FunctionName` function that is defined inside the auto-generated proxy file.

Any tips about how to be able to gracefully handle this exception ?

Comment: Ensure your async method you are calling is returning Task or Task<T> and not **void** otherwise you will not be able to catch the exception in a try-catch. [MSDN Mag: Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty difficult to know exactly what is happening; however, I'm going to assume you have a web service like such

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    String Hello(String Name);

    [OperationContract]
    Person GetPerson();
}
```

You probably have a proxy like this :

```
public class MyPipeClient : IMyService, IDisposable
{
    ChannelFactory<IMyService> myServiceFactory;

    public MyPipeClient()
    {
        //This is likely where your culprit will be.
        myServiceFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress(Constants.myPipeService + @"/" + Constants.myPipeServiceName));
    }

    public String Hello(String Name)
    {
        //But this is where you will get the exception
        return myServiceFactory.CreateChannel().Hello(Name);
    }

    public Person GetPerson()
    {
        return myServiceFactory.CreateChannel().GetPerson();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ((IDisposable)myServiceFactory).Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you have an error connecting you will get it not when you try to connect to the channel factory but when you actually try to call a function.

To fix this problem, you can put a try catch around every single function call and handle async calls manually.

Conversely, you can have a function like init() that is called synchronously every single time you instantiate a connection. This way you know that if that call connects that you have a connection.

If you are at risk of a connection dropping at any time I advise you go with the former option.

Anyway here is an example of how you'd fix it:

```
public class MyPipeClient : IMyService, IDisposable
{
    ChannelFactory<IMyService> myServiceFactory;

    public MyPipeClient()
    {
        myServiceFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress(Constants.myPipeService + @"/" + Constants.myPipeServiceName + 2) );
    }

    public String Hello(String Name)
    {
        try 
        {
            return Channel.Hello(Name);
        }
        catch
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }

    public Person GetPerson()
    {
        try 
        { 
            return Channel.GetPerson();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Task<Person> GetPersonAsync()
    {
        return new Task<Person>(()=> GetPerson());
    }

    public Task<String> HelloAsync(String Name)
    {
        return new Task<String>(()=> Hello(Name));

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        myServiceFactory.Close();
    }

    public IMyService Channel
    {
        get
        {
            return myServiceFactory.CreateChannel();
        }
    }
}
```

I uploaded the source I wrote so that you could download the full source. You can get it here  : https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfPipeExample

PS : This Repository throws the exception you are getting. In order to remove it just go to MyPipeClient and remove the + 2 in the constructor.

If you are using a Duplex, Consider using this repository:
https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfDuplexPipeExample